# Is there anyother way to call a method in FragmentActivity other than starting it using intents?

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, android-dialogfragment

Is there any other way to call a method in `FragmentActivity` other than starting it using `Intents`?
Can anyone please help?

**Code is given below:**

```
    class MainActiviy extends Activiy{
   //some code
   //here i need to show a dialog
 }


class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

int mNum = 0;
static MyDialog newInstance(){
    return new MyDialog();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //dialog view
    Log.i("MyDialog", "onCreateview");
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, container, false);
    TextView v1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
    v1.setText("dialog shown");
    return v;
}

}


public class DialogActivity extends FragmentActivity{

DialogFragment dialogfragment;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


}
void show(){
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");

    if(f != null){
        ft.remove(f);
    }

    dialogfragment = MyDialog.newInstance();

    dialogfragment.setCancelable(false);
    dialogfragment.show(ft, "dialog");
    dialogfragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog);

}
}
```

> Is there any other way to call the `show()` method in `DialogActivity` from
>   another Activity class??

Comment: Is your another activity started by DialogActivity?

Comment: no..that activity is the mainActiviy.from there i need to show a dialog.so that i added dialogfragment.but iam not able to use this

Comment: I am little bit lost. Reason why you want that is that you don't want copy whole method show() when you want to show dialog in another activity?

Comment: if i simply copy show() method to activiy.then getSupportFragmentManager() will be showing error.because it need FragmentActiviy right?

Comment: i tried that method also by using getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager() but it was null pointer execptn

Comment: You are in another activity (in the foreground), and you want to remove that Fragment from DialogActivity, which is in the background. Am I right?

Comment: no.now i am in a foreground activity. when i do some task,say,pressing button, i need to show a dialog(this dialogfragment).

Comment: Yes you can't use Activity with fragments. And why you can't replace Activity with FragmentActivity??

Comment: You can't have 2 activity displayed at the same time. If your "another activity" is contained in DialogActivity, then your "another activity" is (or at least should be) a Fragment, not an Activity.

Comment: its not directly extended from activity class.It is extended from another activiy class.

Comment: but this DialogActivity is fragmentActiviy.so both are different rt?

Comment: or any other way that i can directly use that dialogfragment without using fragmentactiviy?

Comment: FragmentActivity is used by compatibility library (comes from   `android.support.v4.app`) and is used to add Fragment compatibility to old version of Android. But FragmentActivity IS an Activity, not a Fragment. As a proof, [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) extends Activity, not Fragment!

Comment: @Kyriog so no other way other than extending the mainactivty by FragmentActiviy

Comment: Just to be sure, your main activity is DialogActivity, right? Or is it another activity?

Comment: @Kyriog no another activiy.. code edited

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33132/discussion-between-kyriog-and-sjk)

Answer (score 1):

In order to display a Dialog, you should follow [the official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) published by Google.

Comment: ya that way only tried.but i was searching for some other way of implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest simply putting the `DialogFragment` in a separate class. That way you can call it from your `FragmentActivity` and from anywhere else in the app. Seems to be more straightforward and clear than trying to call it through a `FragmentActivity`.

However, if that is indeed what you are trying to do, I haven't done that with a `FragmentActivity` before but I have with a Fragment. If your `FragmentActivity` dynamically loads up a `Fragment`, you can add a tag as you have done, allowing you to access that `Fragment` elsewhere in the app very simply.

I know for sure you can access any visible `Fragment` methods via that method and if you included the show() method with that dynamically added `Fragment`. You could achieve it, very roundabout though.

Either way, I would personally separate the `DialogFragment` and create a helper method, maybe in the `Application` object to take care of some of the boilerplate code if it was heavily used.

Cheers

Comment: but i need to support older version.so i am forced to use fragmentActivity so that only i can get getSupportFragmentManager().

Comment: Currently you have created a DialogFragment and provided a show() method all from within your Activity / FragmentActivity (that part makes no difference). What I am proposing is that you take all that DialogFragment related code out of your Activity. That was if you want to show it from your Activity, you create a new instance and show it.. something like DialogFragment dialogFragment = MyDialog.newInstance(); dialogFragment.show(); BUT and this is key, you can also do that from anywhere in your app, you can call the same dialog regardless of where you are in your app.

Comment: If you are concerned about accessing the DialogFragment from elsewhere. Then why not make the DialogFragment it's own separate entity that can be called from anywhere. There is no benefit I can see to localizing it by doing all the creation and initialization in that Activity when you want to call it from elsewhere as well. The support library makes no difference whatsoever in this case though

Comment: As u mentioned, making MyDialog as a separate class is fine.   but to show that myDialog cannot be done by   **DialogFragment dialogFragment = MyDialog.newInstance(); dialogFragment.show();**    In activity  class it should be called as    **dialogFragment.show(FragmentManager manager, String tag);**    which is difficult because in FragmentManager field I need supportFragmentManager to support older version.So fragmentActivity is becoming an issue.

Comment: As far as I can see, with a separate class you can get a concrete DialogFragment wherever you are Activity, Fragment, FragmentActivity etc. The mechanism of actually showing the DialogFragment does vary, yes. But it is a simple case of using a FragmentActivity instead of normal Activity, the DialogFragment is still the same and can be shown from anywhere.     I guess it depends quite a lot on whether your question is show the same DialogFragment from anywhere or indeed call any FragmentActivity method from anywhere. If it is the latter, this is all irrelevant :)

Comment: _ya i am agreeing to what you are saying that dialogFragment can be made as separate class_.  But anyway for using it i need to use a fragmentActivity (to get **getSupportFragmentMAnager**).  From there only i can call that dialogFragment class to show the dialog.  That is why i asked how to call fragmentActivty method from another Activity class.My app contains different parts so i cant simply change the Activiy to FragmentActivity.

Comment: If you're application needs the support libraries, wouldn't you have a whole load of FragmentActivities anyway? Therefore, you can still get the fragmentSupportManager from any of them?

Comment: how will i get getSupportFragmentManager() without FragmentActivity?In my app fragment is not yet used.Now i added this dialogfragemnt only because **showdialog() is depreciated and solution given in site is using DialogFragment** .App is supporting 2.3.3 ownwards.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding me. I propose using FragmentActivities, everywhere if you want. Whether you are in an Activity or in a FragmentActivity, you can get either the fragmentManager or supoortFragmentManager. The whole point is once you have created a DialogFragment, you can get the supportFragmentmanager from what FragmentActivity you are in. You use FragmentActivities. However, instead of trying to call a method in a different Activity/FragmentActivity, you could just get the supportFragmentManager from there and create the DialogFragment.

Comment: both fragmentActivity and Activity will be same?If i change all activities to fragmentActivty ,it wont affect functionality??

Comment: Not as far as I know. FragmentActivity is a subclass of Activity adding more functionality. So you should be able to make all Activities FragmentActivities. If your problem was how to get supportFragmentManager(), just make all Activites FragmentActivities :)